# Solr sort by snippet count

Tags: solr

I'm using Solr 4.4. Have a field named text which has termVectors, termPositions and termOffsets set to true. With Highlighting parameters I'm able to get the snippets and their count.

But I'm unable to find a way to sort by the snippet count. Is this possible in Solr.

Answer (score 0):

You could also define the default sorting of results using the concept of **relevancy**. Perhaps [the Solr relevancy cookbook](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyCookbook) would help you to adjust your system.

Hope I helped!